I want to plot a semi-random graph in Matlab
Our sample set is given as {-1,1.5,2,2.5}.
b = from "outcome" value to outcome(index100) value.
There is a problem that outcome(1) cannot be equal to a matrix value. Hence I set "outcome" (without (1)index) equal to the matrix value. But unfortunately, yet > or < operators cannot work with a matrix value, And I don't know how to work with rand function.
In fact, I like when a negative value is randomly chosen then the next time double of it being selected, but when a positive random value is chosen it don't get doubled.
I give you the code:
sample={-1,1.5,2,2.5};
for i=1:100
    z=i;
    outcome=randsample(sample,1);
    if outcome>0
        z=1;
    else
        z=i;
        outcome(z)=(2^z)*outcome;
    end;
    if i==1
        result=outcome;
    end;
end;
b = outcome:outcome(100);
result = sum(b,"all");
plot result;
end

Any vision for helping me?

Before trying to solve the issue I'd recommend that you fix the indentation and the variable naming of your code. Looking at the code I have no idea what a, b and z variables are supposed to do. Use descriptive names for your variables. It would also be a good idea that for a smaller range (eg: for i=1:5) you provide what is the result you expect, so we can better understand what are you trying to do.

Error: Operator '>' is not supported for operands of type 'cell'.

Why are you using a cell anyway? They're best suited for non-numeric or non-uniform data... You probably want to define a numeric array sample=[-1,1.5,2,2.5]; with square brackets

In MATLAB operators < and > CAN and DO indeed operate matrixes . Try : [1 2 3] > [4 5 6]
Result :
1×3 logical array
0   0   0

You intend for result to be a single value, sum of all outcome? Because outcome:outcome(100) is an array with all integer values in between outcome(1) and outcome(100), if both of them are integers, the other values in outcome would be ignored. I think you meant to do outcome(1:100). What is plot result meant to do? outcome(i)=randsample(sample,1); would work if sample is defined as a numeric array as @wolfie suggested.

that outcome:outcome(100) is odd

Thank you Cris and Wolfie. Now it's working:
sample=[-1,-1,-1,1.5,2,2.5];
z=0;
for i=1:100
outcome(i)=randsample(sample,1)*(2^z);
if outcome(i)>0
z=0;
else
z=z+1;
end;
end;
